# API Platform : Best way to custom logic for a GET route

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm new do API PLatform and i don't understand how to do some things.

For some reason, I have a Journal entity with a Content field (text).

In this Content field, I have a chain of Post (Entity) Ids, separated by a "|".

For exemple : "123|256|23|456|894|356|2|1646|998|61|9898|16|665|65|" and so on.

When we request the "/api/journal/1" route with an User ID as parameter, I want to parse the Content Field of the Journal Entity and return all the matching Posts in the right order.

It's not a standard behaviour and i'm very confused when i read the documentation.

Can someone explain to me how i can do this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write some code in your entity, you can for example write your own getter that isnt mapped by ORM...like

```
public function getContentByIdList() {
    $list = explode($this->contentIds, "|");

    // .... here you can write a simeple service to map your ids by your content data.
    // foreach (.... $key => $value){.... $objectList[] = $em->contentRepository()->findById(value)}

    return $objectList;
}
```

but the rly question is why is your data so anti norm form "123|256|23|456|894|356|2|1646|998|61|9898|16|665|65|" instead of a releation ?

Comment: You don't have to connect anything. Api-Platform creates resource API from all of your entities. So you can easily if your entity have a new property -> Api-Platform will handle it itself. So all you have to do is write logic in the getter of your entity, since the getter is called automatically when the API platform calls the GET / resource /. in your example, all getters from your Jurnal Entity will be used. Here it can still come to Sichbarkeits & authorization problems. But that's another topic.

Comment: Do you use the composer package "nelmio / api-doc-bundle" and / or "api-platform / api-pack" that make the handeling of all resource API easier

Comment: Alternatively, just have a look at a tutorial on the topic: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform

Comment: Okay I understand your solution.

For the reasons to use that kind of system instead of a classic relation :

It's because there will be a loooooot of data in the pivot table if I work with relations between Journal and Post.

For exemple : A User Journal keep ref of of every post published by every user present in the "Place" where the user is. If the user change to another place, the Journal stops storing the posts of the place 1 and store the posts of place 2.